# Supervisord maximum process number

Tags: supervisord

So i was trying to start some extra processes in my supervisord like i have done before but i got this message

```
 <class 'xmlrpclib.ProtocolError'>, <ProtocolError for 127.0.0.1/RPC2: 500 Internal Server Error>: file: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/supervisor-3.0-py2.6.egg/supervisor/xmlrpc.py line: 470
```

I restarted the whole thing, and i got the same error when starting the same number of processes. Is there a way to give a second rpc interface or will i have to run a second supervisord process? Will i need to define something different other than pids and socks in its conf if thats the case?

Answer (score 2):

**Change your port**

```
socket=tcp://localhost:8003
```

Answer (score -1):

I happened across this error myself and discovered that I had accidentally set the `command` directive in my supervisor ini file for that process to nothing because I had accidentally moved it to the next line:

```
[program:myapp]
command=
/myapp/command/to/start
directory=/path/to/myapp/
user=myapp_user
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```

I think I was editing something and forgot to put it back.  Maybe this is related to your problem?